# Existence of $x\in \mathbf{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function. Then which of the following is false?

$(a)$ There exists $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=\frac{f(0)+f(1)}{2}$.

$(b)$ There exists $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=\sqrt{f(0)f(-1)}$.

$(c)$ There exists $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(t) dt$.

$(d)$ There exist $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=$$\int_{0}^{1} f(t) dt$.

Please tell me how to solve this problem?

I tried this but could not solve it.

Comment: Please show us your work,  and avoid the imperative.

Comment: This problem is new to me.I really don't know how to start.I tried this problem.But I don't know which theorem should I use?

Comment: Have you recently learned the intermediate value theorem, and possibly the mean value theorem for integrals...?

Comment: First you need to notice that $\frac{f(0)+f(1)}{2}$ is a number between the maximum and the minimum of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. Likewise $\sqrt{f(0)f(-1)}$ is between $f(0)$ and $f(-1)$. The intermediate value theorem tells you that $f$ takes all values between any two values that it takes. Therefore (a) and (b) are always true.

Comment: In the case of (d) notice that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)=\frac{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)}{1-0}$ is an average of the values of $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$. So, it is similar to (a). We can prove that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)$ is between the maximum of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$  and the minimum on the same interval. Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem again it should take that value too.

Comment: (c) you can see it is similar to (d) but not quite. The length of the interval of integration is $2$. But there is no division by $2$ this time. That hints that it should not be true always. In fact, take a function that is larger than $1/2$ on $[-1,1]$ and smaller than $3/4$ everywhere. Then $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)>2\times1/2=1$. Since $f(x)<3/4$ it never takes the values $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what theorems to use, think about counter examples.

**Hint:** For item $c$, let $f$ be a constant function.

Answer (score -2):

$(a) $ is true cause $f ([0,1]) $ is an interval and $\frac {f (0)+f (1)}{2}\in [f (0),f (1)] $.

$(d )$ is true, using the first mean formula of integral. $$\int_0^1f=f (x)(1-0) .$$

$(c) $  is not true. if $f (x) =1$ then $\int_{-1}^1f =2\ne f (x) $.

Comment: $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: For (c) they need $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt=f(c)$ not equal to $2f(c)$.

Comment: @uSir470888 Look now. it is better.

Comment: Yes. It works now.